# Can an axisymmetric solution produce antisymmetric eigenfunctions?

Tags: symmetry, eigenvalue, vibrations, solid-mechanics

I'm solving a vibrating membrane. In order to simplify my calculations, it's tempting to assume axisymmetric behaviour. If I solve an axisymmetric problem, am I going to lose all the [antisymmetric mods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrations_of_a_circular_membrane#Animations_of_several_vibration_modes)?

Comment: If you assume that your solution is axisymmetric, then yes, it certainly won't reproduce any non-symmetric modes. But you can quite simply solve the general problem using separation of variables, and it's done in the article you link to.

Comment: My intention was to solve numerically, and solving full 3d is computationally expensive.

Comment: As I just said, you can solve numerically for the radial part, having additional term from separation of variables, which would take the angular dependence into account (assuming you only want to use a single angular mode, not a superposition of them).

Comment: And if I solve for a 1/4 of the domain with symmetry boundary conditions, will I get all the angular modes of the original problem?

Comment: All this depends on what actual problem you're trying to solve. Could you expand your question to at least include the equation you're solving and the boundary conditions? Would also be better if you described, how you choose your quarter of the domain — there're infinite number of ways to do this.